# squid proxy random IP time change

Tags: squid

I have included two IP addresses in squid with random TCP outgoing addresses but I need them as one IP will be active for 15 minutes and the other one will be active for 15 minutes and this will repeat.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You probably can't out of the box. What problem are you *actually* attempting to solve?

Comment: look two random IPs are rotating when I check but when i will open a website first ip will open the website for 15 min after 15 minutes the IP will shift to the next